# R Markdown equation ` lefted as group` for Word

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown

I know we can use  `$$ \begin{aligned} ....\end{aligned} $$` to realize math equation formulas alignment in Word using R Markdown. However, if I want to the `entire equation` (may be multiple lines) `lefted as group` in R Markdown for Word, how do I get that?

I also search [here](https://superuser.com/questions/873769/auto-align-left-equations-in-office-word-2013) trying to use `reference_docx: template.docx`  to get `lefted as group` (or `lefted as group` after `2em indent`), but there seems to be only `centered as group` in Word!

My test example is given as follows:

````
---
output:
  word_document: 
    reference_docx: template.docx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
$$
\begin{aligned}
a &= b+c \\
&= (b1+b2)+(c1+c2)
\end{aligned}
$$
hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha
````

I want to get (`lefted as group` after `2em indent`)

```
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
    a = b+c
      = (b1+b2)+(c1+c2)
hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha
```

other than (`centered as group`)

```
blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla
                           a = b+c
                             = (b1+b2)+(c1+c2)
hahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha
```